# How do I get related data of a different type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have
[these two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvQ1f.png)
with a relation Recipient-AccountID (Recipient is also an int ID) and I want to make a SELECT query which would take recipient's username from the other table and the rest of the message data. I found that I should probably use INNER JOIN for that, but I noticed it's used for data of the same type. I don't need AccountID but Username of that ID. How can I do this in a single SELECT statement?

Comment: INNER JOIN can be used to retrieve data of different types from 2 tables. However, you must specify 1 or more columns of the same type inside the INNER JOIN syntax so the query knows which fields to join on.

Comment: Please show us example of data of table Account and example of data of table Messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select m.MsgID, m.msgBody, a.username
from Messages m join Accounts a on m.recipient = a.AccountID
where //Your where condition
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! So a simple JOIN is enough I see.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT msg.MsgBody,[other msg data],acc.username FROM Accounts as acc
INNER JOIN Messages as msg ON acc.AccountID = ms.Recipient
```

Comment: Works as well, even with AS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Username FROM Accounts
    INNER JOIN Messages On Messages.Recipient = Accounts.AccountID
```